# Output "█" with ncursesw in C

Tags: c, unicode, ncurses, curses

I'm making a tetris game in C to run on an embedded system, but I'd like to have a mock up interface made using Block characters such as "█" (UNICODE 0x2588).

I'm already using ncursesw and have heard mentions of using wprintw() instead of prints().

```
printw("%i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i\n",board[0][i],board[1][i],board[2][i],board[3][i],board[4][i],board[5][i],board[6][i],board[7][i], piece);
```

What should this line be in order to output "█"?

Comment: http://site.icu-project.org/

Answer (score 2):

The are no print functions, just the `addwstr` functions:

```
addwstr, addnwstr, waddwstr, waddnwstr, mvaddwstr, mvaddnwstr, mvwaddwstr, mvwaddnwstr 
- add a string of wide characters to a curses window and advance cursor
```

and add_wch functions:

```
add_wch, wadd_wch, mvadd_wch, mvwadd_wch, echo_wchar, wecho_wchar 
- add a complex character and rendition to a curses window, then advance the cursor
```

Some of the characters have macros e.g. `WACS_BLOCK` for a block.

For your code you would have to make the `wchar_t` string and then use `addwstr`

Comment: How are there "no print functions" …? printf and printw are among the most comment c functions, even used in practically every "hello world" example.

Comment: There are no "print" functions for the `wchar_t` and `cchar_t` functions because there has been little demand for them: X/Open curses did not define these, but provided the conversion function `settchar` (`wchar_t` to `cchar_t`). Your operating system provides conversions between `wchar_t` and `char`.  ncurses happens to diverge from X/Open by accepting multibyte character strings in the current locale, e.g., UTF-8 encoding for printw, etc., but as a rule ncurses does not add extensions which can be done outside the library.