# using extended ASCII characters in printed array

Tags: c, ascii, dos, ncurses, extended-ascii

How do I go about using extended ASCII characters in lieu of regular characters?

I'm making a pong game and currently have `|` characters making up the paddle, however I want ASCII 219 (a solid rectangle) to make it up. here's my code so far

```
    char right_paddle_chars[] = {   '|',
                                    '|', 
                                    '|', 
                                    '|',
                                    '|', 
                                    '|',
                                    '|',    };

    paddle_id = create_big_sprite(75, 10, 1, 7, right_paddle_chars);
```

Comment: You're aware that DOS's extended-ASCII characters will only render correctly under DOS? Don't want to use a proper graphics library?

Comment: Try `#define SOLID_RECT (219) char right_paddle_chars[] = { SOLID_RECT, SOLID_RECT, ...`

Answer (score 2):

"Extended ASCII" is a [meaningless term](http://literarydevices.net/oxymoron/) which is used frequently.  Perhaps you are referring to the graphics in one of the IBM codepages, e.g., 850 (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195064.aspx), which shows "Code Page 850 MS-DOS Latin 1").

However, if you are using ncurses, you are likely using it on some non-DOS system (such as Unix, Linux or BSD), and most recent systems use UTF-8 encoding.  Again, Microsoft documents the equivalents for Unicode (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305160.aspx)).  Codepage 850's `0xdb` maps to Unicode `0x2588`.

Using *ncursesw* (the wide-character flavor), you could have an array of `wchar_t` (wide-characters) holding the Unicode values of your choice, and print that as a string using `addwstr`.

Given that information, you can see that this question has been asked in a different fashion here: [Output “█” with ncursesw in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973052/output-%E2%96%88-with-ncursesw-in-c/16985732#16985732).